# JasperReports' iReport - Passing Date parameter from iReport to Jasper Repository

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

The Date parameter I have set in iReport prompts for the date to use when generating a report. This prompt does not pass to the repository when I upload the report to it.
Can any one explain how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly create "input controls" in JasperReports Server. Once you realize that this is required, it's pretty easy to figure out how to do it.

Comment: To add to your comment: create an input control and from there choose a "single value" type of input control and when you edit the local resource you can choose a "date" type input control.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I have a date parameter set up in iReport which allows me to choose any date of my choice from a calendar, using a java.util.Date expression. How can I have this functionality replicate on the repository through the input control configuration frames?

Comment: Thanks Precose, great info. So close now. I have a date input prompt now on the repository server. However, the date I choose is not linked to the report. My report query uses the current date with the add date construct, interval 2 days. Is there a MySQL or iReport method to link them?